# stylesheet MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-5

I'm working a website using vue.js.
I copy a folder named `_variables.scss` in `node-modules` and `bootstrap` file.To make customize Bootstrap have work, but my `index.html` can't loaded stylesheet not loaded because of MIME styel.
This is error message:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/src/stylesheets/all.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

This is my project's structure:

```
public
|-index.html
src
|-stylesheets
  |-helpers
    |-_variables.scss
  |- all.css
  |- all.css.map
  |- all.scss
```

and this is my all.scss to show how I import bootstrap

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/_functions";
@import "helpers/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

I don't know how to check correct path and router configuration.

I tried changing type="text/html" and type="text/css" but nothing work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico"> -->
    <title>Test Project</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="../src/stylesheets/all.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```